# OpenEJB Standalone -- Non-JMS MDB Fails to Deploy

Tags: java, openejb

I just want to go 'live' with the setup that is currently working beautifully in testing. I've downloaded the standalone OpenEJB server and put my EJBs in the `/apps` directory.

The output in the logs suggests the standalone server may not support non-JMS adapters:

```
Deployment 'SocketMDB' has message listener interface com.example.TCPMessageEndpoint but this MDB container only supports interface javax.jms.MessageListener
```

Note the other modules, *including the RA itself* seem to startup successfully. The only issue seems to be with creating *consumers* of non-JMS messages.

What else might I try to look at or configure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the testing scenario we wrap all the modules we find in the classpath up into an EAR and deploy that.  To mimic that environment, try putting your rar and ejbs into an EAR file and drop that into the `apps/` directory.  You should get the same results as with an embedded scenario.

Comment: What a great project, by the way. I can't tell you how happy I am with it.

Comment: That's wonderful to hear, thank you so much! We can always use more contributors :)  Docs, examples, coding all are welcome.  Tweets and blog posts too.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up just driving an embedded OpenEJB container for further testing. Will try to post new results here when I have them.